# visudo + how to get access to user from other user

Tags: permissions, users, non-root-user

On my Linux Red Hat machines, I do the following from root

```
# su - starus
$                <--   now I am in starus user

$ su - moon      <-- now I want to access moon user from starus user
Password:
```

But I get prompted for a password!

Please advise why I get password if already added in `visudo` the following

```
moon ALL=(starus) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

What is wrong?

I also try to run the following script as user moon but password is needed

```
starus@host sudo -u moon  /home/USER261/test.bash
[sudo] password for starus:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `root` can become any user without needing a password. That's one of the privileges of being the super user. So, with `su - starus`, you can switch to `starus` without being prompted. However, at that point, you are `starus` and no longer `root`, so you do need a password to switch to `moon`.

The simple solution is to switch back to `root` first (just run `exit`) and then switch to `moon`.

Now, `visudo` is irrelevant here. You're not using `sudo` so any changes you make there (in `/etc/sudoers`, the file that `visudo` edits) won't affect the behavior of `su`, only that of `sudo` which is not the same program.

In any case, the line you show (`moon ALL=(starus) NOPASSWD: ALL`) simply means that the user `moon` can run any command as the user `starus` with `sudo` without needing to enter a password. It doesn't mean that anyone can become `moon` without knowing `moon`'s password. It just means that commands like this don't need a password:

```
moon@host $ sudo -u starus command
```

If you are logged in as `moon`, you can use `sudo` to run a command as `starus` without a password.

Comment: see please my update " sudo -u moon  /home/USER261/test.bash" I also try to run command as script from user moon but password again appears

Comment: @yael yes, because you are `starus` trying to run as `moon` and not `moon` trying to run as `starus`. If you are `moon`, you can do `sudo -u starus` with no password, but if you are `starus` you still need a password to run things as `moon`.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the `/etc/sudoers` file is only used by the `sudo` program – not `su`.

It is not used by the `su` program which starts a new shell as the specified user. When you run `su - moon`, you’re starting a new login shell as the *moon* user and you’ll be prompted for that user’s password. When running this command as *root*, you aren’t prompted for the user’s password since *root* is the superuser and could change the password if it wanted to.  However, when running the command as the *starus* user, you’re not a superuser and must authenticate as normal.

On the other hand, the edits that you’ve made to `/etc/sudoers` allow the *starus* user to use the `sudo` command with the `-u` option to run commands as the *moon* user (without being prompted for a password).  E.g., while logged in as *starus*, you could run the following command:

```
sudo -u moon touch /home/moon/test.file
```

Running `sudo -u moon ls -l /home/moon/test.file` would show that the newly created `test.file` is owned by the *moon* user (as if it was *moon* that ran the command and not *starus*).